# Rails 3.2.3 - how to setup routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are the url I need to be in my Rails application

```
site.com
site.com/page/11

site/tags/my_tag
site/tags/my_tag/page/123
```

where `page` and `tags` are actions of `HomeController`. So how must the file `routes.rb` look like in this case?

Comment: You should check the documentation before asking: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: and what have you tried? did it work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should start with:

```
match '/page', :to => 'home#page'
match '/tags', :to => 'home#tags'
```

Comment: Эх, Серега, Серега. Это у меня уже есть.